# waffle custom error page in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, waffle

I am using waffle 1.7 + spring 4 + spring security 3.2 + thymeleaf. My problem is, that I am unable to provide custom error page when fall-back form logging fails. This is my configuration:
    `@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint())
                .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied")
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(waffleNegotiateSecurityFilter(),
                        BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }`

When user uses browser with SNPENGO off and enters wrong credentials, the default system 500 page appears with following information:

`com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Win32Exception: The logon attempt failed.    waffle.windows.auth.impl.WindowsAuthProviderImpl.acceptSecurityToken(WindowsAuthProviderImpl.java:134)
waffle.servlet.spi.NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider.doFilter(NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider.java:103)   waffle.servlet.spi.SecurityFilterProviderCollection.doFilter(SecurityFilterProviderCollection.java:130)
...`

How can I provide my custom page (access-denied.html thymeleaf template) ? So far I have tried everything from http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into Spring documentation and tracking what actually waffle does I have been able to solve it in the following "ugly" way. 1. disabling security for /access-denied page to prevent endless redirection loop 2. wrapping waffle filter to catch all exceptions and redirect it

Does anyone have better solution ?

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/access-denied")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**")
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint())
            .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied")
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(waffleNegotiateSecurityFilter(),
                    BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
}

public class WaffleWrapperSecurityBean extends GenericFilterBean {
    @NotNull
    private final GenericFilterBean wrappedFilter;
    public WaffleWrapperSecurityBean(GenericFilterBean filter) {
        wrappedFilter = filter;
    }
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            wrappedFilter.doFilter(request, response, chain);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ((HttpServletResponse) response)
                    .sendRedirect("access-denied?message="
                            + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        wrappedFilter.destroy();
    }
}
// controller code ommited
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try creating a [DelegatingNegotiateSecurityFilter](https://github.com/dblock/waffle/blob/master/Source/JNA/waffle-spring-security4/src/main/java/waffle/spring/DelegatingNegotiateSecurityFilter.java) and setting an `AuthenticationFailureHandler`.

Example of `DelegatingNegotiateSecurityFilter` bean configuration:

```
<bean id="waffleNegotiateSecurityFilter"
    class="waffle.spring.DelegatingNegotiateSecurityFilter"
    >
    <property name="allowGuestLogin" value="false" />
    <property name="Provider" ref="waffleSecurityFilterProviderCollection" />
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" />
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />
    <property name="accessDeniedHandler" ref="accessDeniedHandler" />
    <property name="defaultGrantedAuthority">
        <null />
    </property>
</bean>
```

- The `AuthenticationManager` allows for the service provider to authorize the principal.
- The `authenticationSuccessHandler` allows for the service provider to further populate the `Authentication` object.
- The `AuthenticationFailureHandler` is called if the AuthenticationManager throws an `AuthenticationException`.
- The `AccessDeniedHandler` is called if the AuthenticationManager throws an `AccessDeniedException`.

I hope this helps ...